# Term queries don't return data and Not analyzed part is not working

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch 1.4.2 and I want to perform Term queries over certain fields and indexes. Therefore, I managed to build the index using the below

```
   curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_river/modelsymptom/_meta -d '{
  "type": "mongodb",
  "mongodb": {
    "servers": [
      { "host": "localhost", "port": 27017 }
    ],
    "db": "bosch",
    "collection": "Model_Symptom",
    "options": { "secondary_read_preference": true },
     "gridfs": false
   },
  "index": {
    "name": "modelsymptom",
    "type": "diagnosis",
    "analyzer": "not_analyzed",
    "mappings": {
    "modelsymptom": {
      "properties": {
            "symptom_id": {
              "type":  "string",
              "analyzer": "not_analyzed" 
        },
          "probability": {
             "type": "string"
        },
          "casue_id": {
            "type": "string"
        },
          "doc_type": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed" 
        },
          "model_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
  }
}'
```

but it is not working, and term queries still don't return any data and when I view the Index Metadat, I see that the Analyzer part sounds to be not applied and also the Probability filed is of type Long although I set it to String

```
{
    "state": "open",
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "creation_date": "1459257376193",
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "number_of_replicas": "0",
            "version": {
                "created": "1040299"
            },
            "uuid": "3srr-KU8TYq8_kYPPaIVZg"
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "diagnosis": {
            "properties": {
                "symptom_id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "probability": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "casue_id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "doc_type": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "model_id": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aliases": []
}
```

code Sample from JAVA API to the term query that don't retrieve any results:

```
 client.prepareSearch(IndexNames.Model_Symptom_ErrorCodeIndex)
                 .setQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("symptom_id", SymptomID))
                            .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("model_id", ModelID)))
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: could you attach example document from your index and search query

Comment: Yes,, It would be helpful if you mention the query you are running

Comment: I have added a code snippet for what I use in my Application

Answer (score 0):

Based on the mapping of your actual index, I'd suggest that elasticsearch receives a document before your mapping is fully applied.

It really looks like the dynamic mapping of elasticsearch, as it cannot know which field should be analyzed and which shouldn't.

You can [disable dynamic mapping in 1.4](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html) with:

```
index.dynamic.mapper: false
```

In general, it is often a good idea to disable dynamic mapping.